# GridView removes row in a wrong way

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, row

I have a gridview and if I remove a row in this way:

```
foreach(Label l in currentRow) // I have an internal list of the labels
{
    grdTable.Children.Remove(l); // the cells are filled with labels
}
grdTable.RowDefinitions.Remove(index);
```

it works if it is the **last** or **second last** row in other cases it fails.

an example where row 2. is deleted (index 1)
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-14074618/Unbenannt.png.html

row 3. is not shown and row 2. is really deleted, but it seems to me that row 3. is not correctly pushed on its right place. even updating the grid didn't help.

**edit:** the current row is a `List<Label>` and I have a `List<List<Label>>` which represents the grid content. I already checked that the `List<Label>` which fills a row has **always** the same index as the RowDefinition which holds it.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are using a `Grid` control, as opposed to a 'GridView' (I'm not aware of any WPF control with that name.)  Your use of `RowDefinitions` is what suggests this to me.

Within a `Grid`, the row each control lies within is given by the value of its `Grid.Row` attached property.  The `RowDefinitions` of the grid specify the heights of each row.

When you delete a `RowDefinition`, all you achieve is adjusting the heights of various rows within the `Grid`.  Deleting a `RowDefinition` does not affect `Grid.Row` values of controls within the grid.

To completely delete the row, you need to:

1. delete all controls in the row,
2. shuffle up all controls in rows below the one deleted, and
3. delete the `RowDefinition`.

Your code appears to be missing step 2.

Your approach works in the case where you delete the last row, because then there are no controls to shuffle up.  It also appears to work in the case where you delete the second-last row. Suppose you have 10 rows, numbered from 0 to 9, and you delete row 8.  There are now 9 row definitions, with numbers 0 to 8.  However, the controls in the last row have their `Grid.Row` value still set to 9, which is now out of range.  WPF puts all controls with the `Grid.Row` out of range in the last row, so the controls in row 9 appear in row 8.  If you add a `RowDefinition` back to the grid, you'll find that the controls in row 9 will then appear in the new row 9, leaving a gap in row 8.

PS. Any reason you're not using a [`DataGrid`](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html)?

Comment: The WPF Toolkit (http://wpf.codeplex.com/) includes a DataGrid control and can be used with .NET 3.5.

Comment: thank you and sorry for my confusing shure it es the grid not gridview. this works fine !

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the exact structure of currentRow and grdTable. Could be something related to something not matching in these. Posting the structure(I mean the data there is and how it is structured) here would help people who try to help you.